# Is the category of $Z^* $ algebra equivalent to the category of $C^*$ algebras

Tags: ct.category-theory, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

A $Z^*$ algebra is a $C^*$ algebra whose all positive elements are zero divisor.
They form a category with usual structures.

**Question**. Is this category equivalent to the category of $C^*$ algebras?

The equivalency means in terms of natural transformation between functors.
If the answer would be affirmative then the study of (category of) $C^*$ algebras would be equivalent to study of (category of) $Z^*$ algebras.

Comment: Where does this definition come from? Note that $C(X)$ is not a $Z^*$-algebra for any compact X, and also $C_0({\mathbb R}^n)$ is not a $Z^*$-algebra. Unital $C^*$-algebras are not $Z^*$-algebras.

Comment: @YemonChoi Yes algebras you mentioned are not $Z^*$ algebra. But a commutative algebra $C_0(X)$ is a $Z^*$ algebra iff $X$ is not approximately sigma compact

Comment: A space X is approximately sigma compact if it has a dense sigma compact subspace. For exqmple the long line is not approximately sigma compqct

Comment: Which category of $C^*$-algebras do you mean?

Comment: I mean the  usual  category of  all  C^*  algebra(including unital one

Comment: @DavidRoberts  May be  I  did not  understand  well  your  previous  comment?

Comment: @Ali I mean to ask what are the morphisms? And do you mean to include *non* unital ones?

Comment: @DavidRoberts Yes w  consider  all possible  morphisms(unital or  non unital). However the "exclusively unital morphisms" produce  another  question

Comment: @Ali I assume you mean strictly continuous, though? I was just curious, that's all.

Comment: @DavidRoberts  I am reading  your  post  below  to  have  a  better  imagination of the  story: I  think  you  are indicating to woronowich morphism. any way  what  would  be  happen  if  I  simply  assume that the morphisms  are  usual  morphisms  between  C^* algebras(According  to  my  main question in this post)?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372841/pushout-of-c-algebras-using-generalised-morphisms

Answer (score 2):

There is at least an easy faithful functor from the category of C${}^*$-algebras into the category of Z${}^*$-algebras. Fix an uncountable set $X$ and map the C${}^*$-algebra $A$ to the Z${}^*$-algebra $C_0(X;A)$. A morphism $f:A \to B$ would go to the morphism $(x_i)_{i \in X} \mapsto (f(x_i))_{i \in X}$. However, this can take non-isomorphic C${}^*$-algebras to isomorphic Z${}^*$-algebras (e.g., any time $A$ and $A \oplus A$ are not isomorphic).

Comment: Thank you  and  +1  very much  for  your  answer

Comment: Do  you mean that $C_0(X,A\oplus A)\sim C_0 (X\times X,A)$ hence isomorphic  to  $C_0(X,A)$  since  $X$ homeomorphic  to  $X\times X$? Or  you mean some  things  else?

Comment: Well, $C_0(X, A\oplus A) \sim C(X,A)$ because $X$ is in bijection with $X \coprod X$ (disjoint union of two copies of $X$). We need $X$ to be uncountable so that anything in $C_0(X,A)$ is zero off of a proper (because countable) subset of $X$, and therefore a zero divisor.

Comment: So your answer is actually  $A\mapsto  A\otimes C_0(X)$. The  tensor product of  a  C^* algebra  and  a  Z^* algebra is   again Z^* algebra. X  being  uncountable is  not an approximately  sigma  compact. After all  I am  really  curious about this category, the  category of  Z^* algebras. Please see my  conversation with David  Roberts about a precise  structure  for  the  category of  C^*  algebras(what kind of  morphisms  we are consideringt, etc). Any way it would be  interesting that the two  categories  would be isomorphic in a  reasonable  sense